# Integrating product of Dirac delta function and it's derivative

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta

Is the following true:
$$ \int \delta(x-a) \frac{\partial^l \delta(x)}{\partial x^l} dx = \frac{\partial^l \delta(x)}{\partial x^l} \Bigg |_{x=a}$$

If not, is there a correct way to evaluate the left hand side?

Thanks!

**Edit/Addition:**

Related: Why/How does WolframAlpha evaluate the following, and in general for odd derivatives?
$$ \int \delta(x) \frac{\partial \delta(x)}{\partial x} dx = \frac{1}{2} (\delta(x))^2 + C $$
[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate(delta(x)*D%5Bdelta(x),x%5D,x))

Comment: how do you define $\delta'$  the derivative of the Dirac ? (and how do you define $\delta$)

Comment: The standard integral definition equation (10) here: [MathWorld - Delta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html)

Comment: $\delta(x)^2$... no sorry you don't understand the definition of $\delta$

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Kurt, I guess, wolfram simply performs integration by parts for your last integral. What concerns your first formula, it can be derived by using the translation (also called filtering) property of the Dirac delta. You can easily evaluate that your both sides of your formula are zero. However, I can not attach a specific meaning to the integrand and I am not sure if someone can.

Comment: Sorry, the answer was for @smörkex.

Answer (score 2):

The convention of calling $\delta$ as 'delta function' need not justify its nature. It is what physicists call a *generalized function* and what mathematicians call a *distribution*, which is defined as continuous linear functional on $C_c^{\infty}(\Bbb{R}^d)$.

One way of giving a meaning to the left-hand side is to interpret them as the following convolution

$$ (\delta * \delta^{(n)} )(a) \text{ $``=$''} \int_{\Bbb{R}} \delta(a-x)\delta^{(n)}(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Since both are compactly supported distributions, the convolution is well-defined. Then we can apply test functions to determine $\delta * \delta^{(n)}$. To this end, let $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$. Then

$$ \langle \delta * \delta^{(n)}, \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta^{(n)}, \delta * \varphi \rangle = \langle \delta^{(n)}, \varphi \rangle $$

and hence $\delta * \delta^{(n)} = \delta^{(n)}$. This is not surprising, since we expect that $\delta$ behaves like an identity element for the convolution operation.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying distributions is a highly dubious activity. There is no reasonable way to extend multiplication to the space of distributions. $\delta(x)^2$ is not a meaningful quantity. So your identities don't make sense. I suspect

If Wolfram alpha is giving an answer for the delta function resulting in a square this is rather worryingly wrong.

---

In general, you can convolve a Delta function with anything
$$\int \delta(x-y) f(y) dy = f(x)$$

so you could interpret you original identity in this sense.

Comment: Thanks, but (1) Wolfram does actually say "$\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function", and (2) what do you think about the main question?

Comment: I have updated the answer.